# In springboot, I can't get the JSON for manytomany with attribute on my REST Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I have a SpringBoot REST API where one or multiple User are part of one or multiple Team (Equipe), but they have a Role for each Team.

When I request my UserRepository.findAll(), I would like to get all my users and their teams and roles.
But when I request my TeamRepository.findAll(), I would like to get all my teams and their users and their roles.

But I don't know how to get a bidirectionnal request. I tried with @jsonmanagedreference and @jsonbackreference but it only allows me to get the teams from the user, and not the opposite.

Currently I have

```
[
{  
        "id": 1,  
        "prenom": "TestPrenom1",  
        "nom": "TestNom1",  
        "roleUserEquipe": []  
}
{  
        "id": 2,  
        "prenom": "TestPrenom2",  
        "nom": "TestNom2",  
        "roleUserEquipe": []  
}
]
```

But what I want is

```
[
{  
        "id": 1,  
        "prenom": "TestPrenom1",  
        "nom": "TestNom1",  
        "roleUserEquipe": [  
                {
                        "role": "Role1",
                        "team": {
                        "id": 1,  
                                "nom": "Team1"
                        }
                }
        ]  
}
{  
        "id": 2,  
        "prenom": "TestPrenom2",  
        "nom": "TestNom2",  
        "roleUserEquipe": [  
                {
                        "role": "Role2",
                        "team": {
                                "nom": "Team1"
                        }
                }
        ]  
}
]
```

And when I request my teams I have

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nom": "Team1",
        "roleUserEquipe": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nom": "Team2",
        "roleUserEquipe": [
            {}
        ]
    }
]
```

But I would like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nom": "Team1",
        "roleUserEquipe": [
                {
                        "role": "Role1",
                        "user": {
                                "id": 1,  
                                "prenom": "TestPrenom1",  
                                "nom": "TestNom1",  
                        }
                },
                {
                        "role": "Role2",
                        "user": {
                                "id": 2,  
                                "prenom": "TestPrenom2",  
                                "nom": "TestNom2",  
                        }
                }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nom": "Team2",
        "roleUserEquipe": []
    }
]
```

My User.java

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe = new HashSet<>();

//GETTERS AND SETTERS AND CONSTRUCTORS

}
```

My Equipe.java (Team)

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Equipe implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String nom;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe = new HashSet<>();

//GETTERS AND SETTERS AND CONSTRUCTORS

}
```

My RoleUserEquipe.java

```
@Entity
public class RoleUserEquipe implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipe_id")
    private Equipe equipe;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private String role;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS AND CONSTRUCTORS

}
```

EDIT :
When debugging, the subobjects are OK: they contain the values that I need.
Only when returning the JSON Response, they lose their values

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work, but try removing the new keywords in:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe = new HashSet<>();
```

to

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "equipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<RoleUserEquipe> roleUserEquipe;
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything different...
What I forgot to say is that when I'm debugging, I can clearly see that my subobjects are OK, but the JSON response doesn't contain them

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us, how you convert your domain objects into resource/DTO objects.

Are you using the Spring ConversionService framework?
If so, show us the converter you wrote. Maybe your converter doesn't take the roles into account?